# Ensure that Vuex Store is fully inialized before rendering component

Tags: javascript, vuex, race-condition

I have been using the way described in [Optimistic Offline-First Apps With Vuex](https://medium.com/daily-now/optimistic-offline-first-apps-with-vuex-d8a412e105a7) to persist my Vuex instance among reloads. I have copied the relevant parts here.

However there is one problem. It seems like there is a race condition, between the components mounting and the cached store being applied.

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    initialized: false,
  },
  mutations: {
    loadFromCache(state, cached) {
      if (cached) {
        Object.keys(cached).forEach((key) => {
          state[key] = Object.assign({}, state[key], cached[key]);
        });
      }

      state.initialized = true;
    },
  }
});

function startLoadFromCache() {
  if (store.initialized) {
    return Promise.resolve();
  }

  return getState()
    .then(state => store.commit('loadFromCache', state));
}
startLoadFromCache();

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>',
  store
});
```

As `getState()` returns a promise, the mutation is not committed synchronously. So how could I either:

- block the execution until the store is fully initalized
- detect that the store isn't initalized and maybe show a spinner meanwhile?

Comment: Why not use v-if inside of component App and show a spinner based on store property initialized?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky the problem is that in some of the components `mounted()` function they already do requests. so if the website/app/whatever is opened again at this route the component start working immediately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is create render the component dynamically

```
<div v-if="activeComponent">
   <component :is="activeComponent"></component>
</div>
```

and then return the component from a computed property.

```
computed: {
    activeComponent(){
        return this.$store.state.initialized ? App : null;
    }
}
```

If you are using `vue-router` you can use a `beforeEach` guard to prevent the rendering page being reached before the app is initialised.